# Unknown function template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-templates

I'm writing a application profiling library that basically hooks Windows APIs and records the parameters and results.  I'm trying to come up with a way to generate these hooks in a manner using C++ templates that requires minimal effort to add new hooks.  Basically, each one of my hooks look like the following:

```
BOOL HookCloseHandle(HANDLE h)
{
    BOOL result = RealCloseHandle(h);
    if(g_profiling) record(result, h);
    return result;
}
```

I want to generalize that via templates so these functions can be generated for any arbitrary Windows API function via `decltype`, e.g. `decltype(CreateFileW)`.  Is this even possible?  I've been looking at `function_traits` in Boost and it seems I'm able to come up with something close:

```
decltype(&CloseHandle) RealCloseHandle = &::CloseHandle;

template <typename R, typename P1, R(*F)(P1)>
R perform_1(P1 value)
{
    R result = F(value);
    if (profiling) record(result, value);
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
T* call(const T& original)
{
    typedef boost::function_traits<T> traits;
    switch (traits::arity)
    {
        case 1:
            return &perform_1<traits::result_type, traits::arg1_type, RealCloseHandle>;
        // ...
    }
    return nullptr;
};

// setup code
Hook(RealCloseHandle, call<decltype(CloseHandle)>());
```

Where `Hook` is provided by the hooking library that replaces a "real" function with my hooked version.

The only thing is, i'm not sure how to remove that `CloseHandle` template argument that's currently inside the `call` function.  Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you just use `call(RealCloseHandle)`?

Comment: I need a templated function that is compiled with the call to `RealCloseHandle` (i.e. it's not passed in), not a function that takes a function pointer as its first argument, so `RealCloseHandle` will need to be a template argument somehow.

Comment: here's my two cents: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a274bbb6fb995209.  The calling syntax is slightly odd, but since it only deals with standard-layout temporaries with no members, it's _trivially_ optimized by the compiler to 0 overhead.

Comment: Your solution looks really promising, but check out how it behaves on MSVC++ 2013:  `var.cpp(31) : fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.`  :(

Comment: @MooingDuck For your solution though, is there a way to get a function pointer to the `()` operator which *matches that of the original function*?  Even the calling convention... (that's what the API hooking library needs)

Comment: @atanamir: Added a `.get()` which returns the original function pointer, clearer calling syntax, and specializations to handle functions that return `void`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9a007634bce38d9.  Visual Studio _claims_ it can handle this version (http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/H1N), did not test my prior.  (Note that this does _not_ do perfect forwarding, so works _very badly_ with large or complex types, but C APIs doesn't have those so...)

Comment: @MooingDuck wow, it's becoming beautiful.  However, I think you misunderstood my previous question -- this is hooking an existing binary's calls, so I need to get a function pointer to the generated implementation (the one with `record()` in it); the function needs to be invokable using the same calling convention as the original function in order to be used as a hook.  Right now it seems that the `operator ()` will be `__thiscall`, whereas the original `CloseHandle` is `__stdcall`, so it seems they aren't compatible.  Is that correct?

Comment: @atanamir: Ooooh, that's correct.  More relevent, they're member functions.  Both are easily fixed: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40c132d2c963a98c (I've renamed it `call` since you'll be wanting something easier to type)

Comment: ....And this time it actually compiles: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3515d42653165348 (Also, a hex upon whoever put the `stdcall` specifiers in a different place than their compeditor!)

Comment: Cool!  I'll try it on my machine now too.  One last question: is it possible to use the calling convention specified in template argument?  i.e. `decltype(CloseHandle)` has the calling convention in it...  other than that, this is really cool.  If you want to put it in as an answer, i can give you the rep for it.

Comment: @MooingDuck: please put it in an answer.  (P.S. GCC 4.9 and ICC 13 can't digest the code -- only CLang seems to be able to.)

Comment: @atanamir: Calling conventions are only sometimes inconsistently part of the type, and in a template argument the calling convention is lost.  Very sad.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the basics look like this:

```
//declare the Wrap type
template<class signature, signature func> struct Wrap;

//template parameters are return type, parameter list, then the actual function
template<class R, class...Ps, R(&func)(Ps...)> 
struct Wrap<R(Ps...), func>
{        
    static R MSVCSTDCALL call(Ps...Vs) GCCSTDCALL
    {
        auto result = func(Vs...);
        if (g_profiling) record_w_ret(Wrap(), result, Vs...);
        return result;
    }
};

//pass the call function of the Wrap object
Hook(CloseHandle, Wrap<void(HANDLE),CloseHandle>::call);
```

However, this doesn't handle `void` returns, so we need a specialization for that:

```
//Wrappers without returns
template<class...Ps, void(&func)(Ps...)> 
struct Wrap<void(Ps...), func>
{        
    static void MSVCSTDCALL call(Ps...Vs) GCCSTDCALL
    {
        func(Vs...);
        if (g_profiling) record_no_ret(Wrap(), Vs...);
    }
};
```

And to fix the ugly usage syntax:

```
//easymode wrapper
#define WRAP(X) Wrap<decltype(X),X>::call

Hook(CloseHandle, WRAP(CloseHandle));
```

However, it has been pointed out to me that using a function pointer as a non-type-template-parameter is illegal and G++ won't take it.  I'll work on that.  Clang and MSVC accept them fine.